# Не видит класс IabHelper

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь добавить встроенные покупки в свое приложение, делаю по оф. мануалу:
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

После добавления .aidl файла в проект, необходимо создать экземпляр класса IabHelper, с которым будет дальше вестись работа:

```
IabHelper mHelper;
```

У меня Android Studio не видит этот класс, никакого импорта автоматически не предлагает.

Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это класс из примера использования in-app billing. Посмотрите в `<sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/samples/TrivialDrive/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util`

По вашей ссылке есть описание, что эти файлы нужно скопировать в проект:

> 3. Add the helper classes from the /util directory of the TrivialDrive sample to your project. Remember to change the package name declarations in those files accordingly so that your project compiles correctly.